# How to instruct Ninject hide a Type from its implicit binding list

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container, ninject.web.mvc

Does Ninject have an attribute which I could use to decorate class or constructor to let Ninject to ignore it?

I need to get rid of:

> A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two
>   services.

This is my code:

```
// Abstraction
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

// Implementation
public class ShipOrderCommandHandler 
    : ICommandHandler<ShipOrderCommand>
{
    private readonly IRepository<Order> repository;

    public ShipOrderCommandHandler(
        IRepository<Order> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void Handle(ShipOrderCommand command)
    {
        // do some useful stuf with the command and repository.
    }
}
```

My generic decorator:

```
public TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand>
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    private ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratedHandler;

    public TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratedHandler)
    {
        this.decoratedHandler = decoratedHandler;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            this.decoratedHandler.Handle(command);
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

My container registration:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
    .To(typeof(TransactionCommandHandlerDecora‌​tor<>));
```

Comment: You could use With.Interception as a way to accomplish the same effect but obv the decorator route is a very valid way to do it.

Comment: I have read the whole Ninject Wiki and do not find how to ignore constructor. With. is good solution but not optimal I will need to place it in every Controller Constructor, it would be more rational to put Ignore on constructor which cause the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example based on your code.

```
public class AutoDecorationFacts
{
    readonly StandardKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel();

    public AutoDecorationFacts()
    {
        _kernel.Bind( typeof( ICommandHandler<> ) )
            .To( typeof( TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator<> ) )
            .Named( "decorated" );
    }

    [Fact]
    public void RawBind()
    {
        _kernel.Bind( typeof( ICommandHandler<> ) ).To<ShipOrderCommandHandler>().WhenAnyAnchestorNamed( "decorated" );
        VerifyBoundRight();
    }

    void VerifyBoundRight()
    {
        var cmd = _kernel.Get<ICommandHandler<ShipOrderCommand>>();
        Assert.IsType<TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator<ShipOrderCommand>>( cmd );
    }
```

Best used with `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions`:-

```
    [Fact]
    public void NameSpaceBasedConvention()
    {
        _kernel.Bind( scan => scan
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InNamespaceOf<CommandHandlers.ShipOrderCommandHandler>()
            .BindAllInterfaces()
            .Configure( x => x.WhenAnyAnchestorNamed( "decorated" ) ) );
        VerifyBoundRight();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void UnconstrainedWorksTooButDontDoThat()
    {
        _kernel.Bind( scan => scan
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .BindAllInterfaces(  )
            .Configure( x=>x.WhenAnyAnchestorNamed("decorated" )));
        VerifyBoundRight();
    }
}
```

Your classes:

public class ShipOrderCommand
    {
    }

```
// Abstraction
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    void Handle( TCommand command );
}

// Implementation
namespace CommandHandlers
{
    public class ShipOrderCommandHandler
        : ICommandHandler<ShipOrderCommand>
    {
        public ShipOrderCommandHandler(
            )
        {
        }

        public void Handle( ShipOrderCommand command )
        {
            // do some useful stuf with the command and repository.
        }
    }
}
public class TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand>
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    private ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratedHandler;

    public TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratedHandler )
    {
        this.decoratedHandler = decoratedHandler;
    }

    public void Handle( TCommand command )
    {
        this.decoratedHandler.Handle( command );
    }
}
```

(used NuGet-latest versions of Ninject and Ninject.Extensions.Conventions)

Comment: How would one add another decorator on top of the transactional decorator (i.e. ExecutionTimeCommandHandlerDecorator)?

Comment: @Discofunk See https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding In general, one uses `WhenInjectedInto` and friends (the `.Named` trick above is as you point out not compositional and to be honest looking at it, I wonder who wrote it!)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Contextual Binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) to `Bind` the raw interfaces with a constraint to make them only be considered in the right context (i.e., when they're going into a decorator).

I have a very similar such `When` extension one I can paste here tomorrow if you're still looking then.

EDIT: The code I had in mind (turns out it doesnt do want you want directly)

```
public static class NinjectWhenExtensions
{
    public static void WhenRootRequestIsFor<T>( this IBindingSyntax that )
    {
        that.BindingConfiguration.Condition = request => request.RootRequestIsFor<T>();
    }
}

public static class NinjectRequestExtensions
{
    public static bool RootRequestIsFor<T>( this IRequest request )
    {
#if false
        // Need to use ContextPreservingGet in factories and nested requests for this to work.
        // http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/12/08/ninject-extension-contextpreservation-explained/
        return RootRequest( request ).Service == typeof( T );   
#else
        // Hack - check the template arg is the interface wer'e looking for rather than doing what the name of the method would actually suggest
        IRequest rootRequest = RootRequest( request );
        return rootRequest.Service.IsGenericType && rootRequest.Service.GetGenericArguments().Single() == typeof( T );
#endif
    }

    static IRequest RootRequest( IRequest request )
    {
        if ( request.ParentRequest == null )
            return request;

        return RootRequest( request.ParentRequest );
    }
}
```

Used to attach decorators:-

```
root.Bind<IEndpointSettings>().To<IAnonymousEndpointSettings>().WhenRootRequestIsFor<IAnonymousService>();
root.Bind<IEndpointSettings>().To<IAuthenticatedSettings>().WhenRootRequestIsFor<IServiceA>();
```

EDIT 2: You should be able to use create a `When` derivative which takes the general binding for IX out of the picture except when it's being `Resolve`d to be fed into a Decorator. Then the `Bind` for your Decorator can either use Context Preservation (@Remo has an article on it) to ensure that gets into the context so your predicate can decide or you may be able to add metadata to the Request and have the When rely on that.

So, I'd:
1. read about Context Preservation
2. examine/dump the contents of the context on the request that comes into your `When` condition and determine how you can appropriately filter.

(And hope someone will come along with a canned one liner answer!)

The Context Preservation extension may have a part to play.

Comment: @Tomas updated again. Sorry it isnt full working code with tests - aint got the time at the moment to do it, fun and all as it would be to work it out!